# Restoring test database for unit testing in Neo4j

Tags: unit-testing, neo4j

I would like to unit test CRUD operations against a pre-populated Neo4j database.

I am thinking that a way to do this might be to:

- Create a an empty database (let's call it `testDB`)
- Create a database backup (let's call it `testingBackup`)
- On running tests:

  - Delete any data from `testDB`
  - Populate `testDB` from `testingBackup`
  - Run unit test queries on the now populated `testDB`

I am aware of the backup / restore functions, the load / dump functions and the export to csv / load from csv etc.  However, I'm not sure which of these will be most appropriate to use and can be automated most easily.  I'm on Ubuntu and using python.

I would need to be able to quickly and easily alter the backup data as the application evolves.

What is the best approach for this please?

Answer (score 1):

I have something dome somthing similar, with some caveats. I have done tests like these using Java and testcontainers. Also, i didn't use neo4j. I have used postgress, sqlserver and mongodb for my tests. Using the same technique for neo4j should be similar to one of those. I will post the link to my github examples for mongodb/springboot/java. Take a look.

The idea is to spin up a testcontainer from the test (ie, a docker container for tests), populate it with data , make the application use this for its database use, then assert at the end.

In your example, there is no testingbackup. Only a csv file with data.

-Your test spins up a testcontainer with neo4j from your test (this is your testdb).

-Load the csv into this container.

-get the ip, port, user, password of the testcontainer (this part depends on the type of database image available for testcontainers. Some images allow you to set your own port, userid and password. Some of them won't.)

-pass these details to your application and start it (i am not sure how this part will work for a python app. here you are on your own. See the link to a blog i found for a python/testcontainer example below. I have used spring-boot app. You can see my code in github)

-once done, execute queries to your containerized neo4j and assert.

-when the test ends, the container is disposed off with the data.

-any change is done to the csv file which can create new scenarios for your test.

-create another csv file/test as needed.

Here are the links,

https://www.testcontainers.org/

testcontainers neo4j module https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/neo4j/

A blog detailing testcontainers and python.
https://medium.com/swlh/testcontainers-in-python-testing-docker-dependent-python-apps-bd34935f55b5

My github link to a mongodb/springboot and sqlserver/springboot examples.
One of these days i will add a neo4j sample as well.
https://github.com/snarasim123/testcontainers

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look.